# why date format is getting changed while reading using Apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache

I am reading excel data using Apache poi As follows

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {   

                Row row = rowIterator.next(); 
                String date_time=row.getCell(0).toString();
                System.ou.println(date_time);
                           }
```

when i read `13/01/2017 10:11:18`
 out put is `13/01/2017 10:11:18`this its okay but when i try to read `12/1/2017 21:17`
 out put is coming wrong as `01-Dec-2017` instead of `12/1/2017 21:17`
how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [12/1/2017 21:17] have different cell format with [01-Dec-2017] in excel, but just looks like [12/1/2017 21:17]

Comment: when i click on that cell 12/1/2017 21:17 like this till the excel format is ok but when i read it problem is coming

Comment: got that, 13/01/2017 is not valid date with format MM/DD/YYYY ,but 12/1/2017 21:17 is. what data format do you want to get? TEXT or DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY??

Comment: @Ashwini Chowdary have you found any solution to the problem you are facing